# Android sticky service not restarted after activity killed

Tags: android, xamarin, service, xamarin.android

I'm working on Xamarin to build an Android application that start a sticky service.
My issue is that when the application is in foreground or background, the service is running smoothly but as soon as I kill the application by swiping it out of the multitasking manager, the service is stopped and doesn't restart.

Here is the code of the activity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Runtime;
using System;

namespace TestAppAndroid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestAppAndroid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(TestService)));
        }
    }
}
```

the service :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;

namespace TestAppAndroid
{
    [Service]
    public class TestService : Service
    {
        static readonly string TAG = typeof(TestService).Name;
        static readonly int TimerWait = 1000;
        Timer _timer;

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            return StartCommandResult.RedeliverIntent;
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            _timer = new Timer(o =>
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, "Hello from simple Service. {0}", DateTime.UtcNow);
            }, null, 0, TimerWait);
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            Log.Error(TAG, "service killed");
        }
    }
}
```

and if it can help the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.random.testapp.testappandroid">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
    <service android:name=".TestService" android:process=":test_service" android:enabled="true"></service>
</manifest>
```

If you guys had any leads on what i'm doing wrong that could really help !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: In the context describe, use `Sticky` vs `RedeliverIntent`

Comment: I tried with Sticky instead of RedeliverIntent and it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't touch the Android manifest and define the service via attributes.

The problem is:

Xamarin generates an `AndroidManifest.xml` that is a merge of the `AndroidManifest.xml` form your project and stuff that is generated from your declarative style using attributes like `Activity, Service, ...`.

This means the actual `AndroidManifest.xml` contains the service twice.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.random.testapp.testappandroid">

    <!-- generated -->
    <service android:name="md5c178831cd46fc53bebc42cf953f78ced.TestService" />

    <!-- manual written -->
    <service android:name=".TestService" android:process=":test_service" android:enabled="true"></service>
</manifest>
```

You can verify it by looking at `.\obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml`.

Remove the line form your projects `AndroidManifest.xml` and use this service:

```
[Service(Enabled = true)]
public class TestService : Service
{
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Don't test it with a debugger attached to it. I think killing the app, will kill the services as well.**

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, that worked perfectly !

Comment: This doesn't work for me.   The part regarding the manifest file was useful as my service wasn't listed.  I did a clean, rebuild and deleted the obj folder and the service is now listed, however; the service dies along with the app and doesn't restart.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you! I had my debugger attached and I couldn't figure out what was going on. What a pain.